# How to set GOPATH on MAC after installing go1.4.1.darwin-amd64-osx10.8.pkg

Tags: go

I have run go1.4.1.darwin-amd64-osx10.8.pkg to install go on my MAC. It install go in /usr/local/go/bin/go.

Can you tell me what should my GOPATH set to? I tried '/usr/local/go' and '/usr/local/go/bin/go'. But both does not seem to be the right path.

Thank you.

Comment: The `GOPATH` variable is the location of all of your projects. It is impossible to tell you what to set this to. For example, I have my `GOPATH` set to `~/.go`, while others may have it set to `~/work/go`, or anything else really. Though, I really suggest you look into something like `homebrew` to install the majority of things on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

GOPATH is an environmental variable used to define the location of your workplace directory. It's used by the Go tools for various reasons.

For example:

`go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode`

- will download the source code and place it at
  `$GOPATH/src/github.com/nsfs/gocode`
- Compile that source code and
  place the binary at `$GOPATH/bin`
- Place symbol and package information at `$GOPATH/pkg/architecture/github.com/nsfs`

The path is also used in other tools:

- `go build github.com/nsf/gocode`
- `go install github.com/nsfs/gocode`

`github.com/nsfs/gocode` in the above commands is resolved automatically to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/nsfs/gocode` and thus you can run these commands without actually being in your workplace (the point of $GOPATH)

The $GOPATH location for your workplace directory can be put anywhere on your machine, but it must minimally have 3 folders (because go get and other tools need these folders).

1. bin
2. pkg
3. src

This environmental variable can be set like any other environmental variable. If you're using go from the Terminal.app, you can set it by opening the file:

`vi ~/.bashrc`

and then setting it

`export GOPATH=~/goworkplace`

`~/goworkplace` is a location to the workplace directory with those 3 folders. It can be anywhere on your system, such as, ~/Development/goworkplace, ~/Desktop/goworkplace, as long as it has those 3 folders

For information, take a look at this: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: I think suggesting that the GOPATH to be /usr/local/go is misleading.

Comment: Yeah totally, I don't know why I used that in the examples. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

First you can check the golang is install or not. Run **go env**

After that you can show the list of go env variables..

then you check where you can install the **go**

after that set **$GOPATH**

like:- **export GOPATH=/var/projects/go**

and also set **$GOBIN**

like:-  **export =$GOPATH/bin**